# Trigonometry Sinusoidal Models (Khan Academy)

Tags: trigonometry

This feels like a very silly question, but I cannot for the life of me see how the following calculation is correct. Although, on Khan Academy, this is the solution. The calculation says $1.5\pi$ multiplied by $1.4706$ is actually equal to $0.7$.

$$\frac{2\pi}3t=1.4706+2\pi n$$
$$t=\frac3{2\pi}(1.4706+2\pi n)$$
$$t\approx0.7+3n$$

This issue keeps reappearing in several problems listed on Khan Academy, and is preventing me from continuing. I feel like the solution is wrong, but since it is occurring multiple times, that I must be missing something obvious. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's using approximate (rounded) value $\approx 0.7$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\pi$ is in the denominator of the fraction.  Using GEMDAS ($G =$ grouping) order of operations, multiply $2$ and $\pi$ in the denominator, then divide $3$ by this product, then distribute.  That's why the $2\pi$'s cancel.  The fraction bar acts as a grouping symbol.